# Mercurial: Merging from unknown divergant 'branch'

Tags: version-control, mercurial, repository

I'm trying to do some work on a project called NS-3, but my problem isn't project specific so I thought I'd ask here as well as the relevant mailing list.

Basically, a copy of the then current project code was made, and a fresh repo made of that code. Work was done on both the 'forked' version and the trunk.

So cloned the forked source, cd in, and `hg pull <latest-dev>`, `hg merge`, and while it wasn't a perfect merge, the changes that were unmergable were all related to one library change, so easily fixed (in theory). Naturally this optimistic attempt failed to build.

Now I'm not entirely sure where to go from here, I'm new to DCVS so please; ideas directed towards a 5 year old!

**How can I find out which changeset of the forked version was last merged against the dev-trunk since they're separate but related repos?**

Comment: It's not quite clear to me what you're asking.  You had development done in "ac copy of the current project code", but it wasn't a clone?  If so how did `hg pull <latest-dev>` work?  You can't pull from a repo that has no common roots (without `-f`, which would be inadvisable).  I'll put in two answers below, one to cover the case when you're merging two repos that starts as copies not clones, and one for the much preferable case where you're just trying to merge two clones.

Comment: Okay, two answers there.  Hopefully one or the other helps.

Answer (score 3):

**The Case Where You Started With a Copy Not a Clone:**

If this is what happened:

1. Project Exists
2. Copy (not clone) of project is made
3. `hg init` is run in each separate copy, creating two *unrelated* repositories
4. work is done in both copies

Then to merge them you want to do this in the newest of the two *unrelated* repos:

1. `hg update 0`, which jumps the repository back to its earliest point -- the point where it last looked identical to the other
2. copy in the contents of the working directory from the *other* repository
3. `hg commit`, which creates a new head
4. `hg merge`, which merges the two heads and also provides a *base* revision, which helps the merge process.

The key is getting a base revision involved if possible.  What DVCS systems bring to the table that CVS and SVN don't is that every merge is a 3-way merge between two heads and the most recent common ancestor.  Faking that common ancestor by creating the new head off the last point the two repos looked the same (revision 0 in the copy) simulates a base revision.

Comment: +1: I think I'm going to meditate on this answer until I fully understand it. The `hg update 0` is giving me a small sense of vertigo.

Comment: The goal was just to get back to the earliest point in time -- the first revision, which has code that's identical in both even if the nodeid isn't.  Essentially get the topology (ancestors, descenents, etc.) to align with how the code evolved.

Comment: I understood that, but it's a way of approaching it that I wouldn't have thought of, so I need to tweak my model a bit.

Comment: By all means, I was just trying to make it more clear.  Ideally one clones instead of copies in the first place, so the other, easier, answer applies.

Answer (score 3):

**The Case Where You Started With a Clone Not a Copy**

This is the classic DVCS case and there shouldn't be much you need to do.  Just go into one of the clones, `hg pull` from the other and fire off the `hg merge`.  If the merge requires input you'll use `hg resolve` to provide it, and when you're done `hg commit`.

If at this point your code isn't building/running then you need to just start debugging. Use `hg blame` to see what was being done near the lines that won't compile and try to suss out what was being done and how to work on it.

The merge process is **much** easier the more frequently you do it.  Pull in up-stream changes daily, not monthly.

You can turn on the [GraphLog](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/GraphlogExtension) extension and use the `hg log -G` command to see the point at which the two lines of development diverged, but in the end merging *is* development, and you just need to approach a non-building merge like you would any other software defect.